# Solving the mystery - VPCs have overlapping IPv4 CIDR blocks

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, vpc-peering

In AWS, When I try to create a peering connection I get this following error

```
Failed due to incorrect VPC-ID, Account ID, or overlapping CIDR range
```

I am not savvy with the networking and wonder how I can solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to rebuild one of your VPCs so the CIDR blocks don't overlap. If you look in the VPC service in the AWS console and look at the CIDR ranges for your VPCs they will have overlap or be exactly the same. A CIDR range is the range of network addresses your VPC is using. Usually this is something like `10.0.0.0/16`.

You can also get this information with the CLI:

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs | jq .Vpcs[].CidrBlockAssociationSet
```